# Forecast of stationary sequence

Tags: time-series, self-study, forecasting, stationarity

Today my professor left us with this task:

Let $\{X_t\}$ be a stationary sequence with mean $\mu$ and covariance $r(\cdot)$. Using prediction equations derive the coefficients $a$ and $b$ prediction $P_{\bar{sp}\{1, X_n\}} = aX_n + b$. Find the corresponding mean squared prediction error.

Can somebody explain to me where I need to start because I'm lost.

Comment: Please explain the notation: what is "$P_{\bar{sp}\{1, X_n\}} $" intended to refer to?  Evidently some quantity is to be predicted based on other quantities, but what specifically are these things?  Maybe $X_{n+1}$ is to be predicted from $X_n$ alone?  Or perhaps it is $X_1$ that is to be predicted?  Or maybe some statistic, such as the mean, of the values from $X_1$ through $X_{n-1}$?